# SQLite3 Python confusing values for columns?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

Part of the program I'm putting together is indexing stock data.
I'm working on a function that takes a dictionary, plays around with it, then inserts its values into my indexing database (whose columns match my keys) using SQLite3.

```
def UpdateIndex(conn, ticker, coldict):
    # Do not change
    itable = "reference"

    #coldict format:
    #{
    #'ticker': 'some string'
    #'starttime': 'some datetime now a string',
    #'endtime': 'some datetime now a string',
    #'var1name': 'some string',
    #'var1method': 'some string',
    #'var2name': 'something here',
    #'var2method': 'something here'
    #... etc.
    #'varNname': 'varN'
    #'varNmethod': 'somestring'
    #}

    coldict['ticker'] = ticker
    exist = CheckIfRowExists(conn=conn, table=itable, ticker=ticker)

    if exist:
        UpdateRowTimes(conn=conn, tablename=itable, coldict=coldict)
    else:
        # Needs debugging
        cols = ', '.join(coldict.keys())
        values = ', '.join(['{}'.format(val) for val in coldict.values()])
        command = """INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ({});""".format(itable, cols, values)
        #print(cols)
        #print(values)
        #print(command)
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute(command)
        conn.commit()
```

I look at it and it seems A-OK. I test it using the following:

```
conn = ConnectSQL("index.db")
coldict = {"starttime": 0, "endtime": 49}
UpdateIndex(conn=conn, ticker="IBM", coldict=coldict)
```

When I run it with the print functions engaged my output looks like

```
starttime, endtime, ticker
0, 49, IBM
INSERT INTO reference (starttime, endtime, ticker) VALUES (0, 49, IBM);
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dominictarro/Desktop/Code/Python/Sparro-Stock/scripts/pipe_inputs.py", line 189, in <module>
    UpdateIndex(conn=conn, ticker="IBM", coldict=coldict)
  File "/Users/dominictarro/Desktop/Code/Python/Sparro-Stock/scripts/pipe_inputs.py", line 102, in UpdateIndex
    c.execute(command)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: IBM
```

Anyone have an answer as to why this is happening? Suggestions on how to fix it?

Also, for any who want to confirm my database is built properly.

```
indexdbname = "index.db"
if os.path.isfile(indexdbname) == False:
    itable = "reference"
    iconn = ConnectSQL(database=indexdbname)
    ic = iconn.cursor()

    statement = """CREATE TABLE {} (
    ticker text PRIMARY KEY,
    starttime text NOT NULL,
    endtime text NOT NULL
    )""".format(itable)
    ic.execute(statement)
    iconn.close()

    print("\'{}\'' made.".format(indexdbname))
else:
    print("\'{}\'' already exists.".format(indexdbname))
```

Comment: Hope that [Little Bobby Tables' company](https://hackaday.com/2016/12/29/if-bobby-tables-had-his-own-company/) never gives out stocks!

Comment: Indexes and columns come from APIs, but yeah that would suck a lot. 
Upstream I have this within a function:

    string = string.translate({ord(c): None for c in '$()/,'})

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Took into consideration Klaus D.'s comment about SQL injection and read up on placeholders. Refactored all of my querying functions to use placeholders.

```
def UpdateIndex(conn, ticker, coldict):
    itable = "reference"
    '''

    coldict format:
    {
    'ticker': 'some string'
    'starttime': 'some datetime now a string',
    'endtime': 'some datetime now a string',
    'var1name': 'some string',
    'var1method': 'some string',
    'var2name': 'something here',
    'var2method': 'something here'
    ...
    'varNname': 'varN'
    'varNmethod': 'somestring'
    }

    '''
    coldict['ticker'] = ticker
    exist = CheckIfRowExists(conn=conn, table=itable, ticker=ticker)

    if exist:
        UpdateRowTimes(conn=conn, tablename=itable, ticker=ticker, coldict=coldict)
    else:
        # Needs debugging
        cols = ', '.join(coldict.keys())
        qmarks = ', '.join(['?' for i in range(len(coldict))])
        command = """INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ({});""".format(itable, cols, qmarks)

        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute(command, tuple(coldict.values()))
        conn.commit()
```